# Passing link text from a hyperlink to another page. (Express JS)

Tags: javascript, html, express

I am facing a challenge in my code where I want to pass a link text in a hyperlink to another page. My web app is build based on Express.

This is the hyperlink (in a dropdown list) in one page:

```html
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/history" ><%=dateArray[index-1]%></a>
```

I want to grab the link text  `dateArray[index-1]`, and send it to `/history` page.

This is relative code in my *app.js*:

```js
app.route("/history")
.get(function(req, res) {
  getDate();
  

  List.find({}, function(err, lists) {
    res.render("history", {
      day: day,
      lists: lists
    });
  });
})
```

Please ignore the irrelevant code here.
What should I do here in app.js to grab the `dateArray[index-1]` value and send it to `/history` route?

Million thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use query string or req.param of express to do that

**Req param (easy and better):**

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/history/<%=dateArray[index-1]%>" ><%=dateArray[index-1]%></a>
```

In Route

```
app.route("/history/:data")
.get(function(req, res) {
    var urlData = req.params.data;
    console.log(urlData);
})
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH Niloy! I am still learning Web development, definitely need to spend more time on documents lol. Thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure, it's always like that. Just keep going. if you want to learn node js and express, this tutorial of net ninja on youtube might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-7RQ46RgxU&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gcy9lrvMJ75z9maRw4byYp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62773679/req-session-returns-wrong-value-after-two-three-requests @Niloy please help me bro

Comment: @DharaniShankar sure, i will try by best.

Comment: @ShiqiZhou if that solved your problem, you can mark this as correct answer