# req.session returns wrong value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**app.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);


const MONGODB_URI =
  'mongodb+srv://@cluster0-szxlh.mongodb.net/shop';


const store = new MongoDBStore({
  uri: MONGODB_URI,
  collection: 'sessions'
});


app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'my secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: store
  })
);


app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("in app");
  res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.session.isLoggedIn;
  res.locals.isShopAuthenticated = req.session.isShopLoggedIn;
  res.locals.isUserAuthenticated = req.session.isUserLoggedIn;
  res.locals.islat=req.session.lat;
  res.locals.islang=req.session.lang;
  res.locals.csrfToken = req.csrfToken();
  console.log(req.session.lat); //returns wrong(previous)value
  console.log(req.session.lang); //returns wrong(previous)value
  next();
});
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
  next();
});
```

**post request which sets the cookie**

```
exports.postHome=(req,res,next)=>{
    const lattitude=req.body.lattitude;
    const longitude= req.body.longitude;
    req.session.lat=lattitude;  //setting session
    req.session.lang=longitude; 
    req.session.save();
    console.log("inpost");
    console.log(lattitude);
    console.log(longitude);
    res.redirect('/');
  }
```

I have used routes after the session middleware.
I have checked in database the value got updated but req.session.lat in app.js returns previously updated value some times

**logs**

inpost
13.336614284510889
80.19245464019774 in app
13.336614284510889
80.19245464019774

inpost
13.334818684323631
80.18992263488768 in app
13.336614284510889 (check it returns previous value sometimes)
80.19245464019774

Comment: are you updating the session while saving lat-long in db?

Comment: no bro iam updating session value which saves in mongoDB and accessing it using req.session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exports.postHome=(req,res,next)=>{
    const lattitude=req.body.lattitude;
    const longitude= req.body.longitude;
    req.session.lat=lattitude;  //setting session
    req.session.lang=longitude; 
    req.session.save(err=>{      
    if(!err)
    {
    console.log("inpost");
    console.log(lattitude);
    console.log(longitude);
    res.redirect('/');
    }
    })
    
  }
```

if req.session.save is synchronized its working correctly.